# iOS - Password save alert controller disappears when app moves to background - How to retain UIAlertController?

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, uialertcontroller

The password save alert controller is shown when the user login. But if the app is moved to background and comes back to foreground the alert controller disappears. This issue occurs only in case of iOS 13 but in iOS 12 it is working fine. Many have reported such issue in case of Custom alert controller https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/123792
But as this issue is related to system alert controller. Looking for a way to fix this?

[image: -c]

Answer (score 0):

It is not the best practice but I can suggest you a workaround. You can hold a boolean value `true` in `NSUserDefaults` when you show `alertController`. After your app comes back to foreground, you can check the boolean if it `true` in the `viewWillAppear`, so you can show it again or bring it front. Don't forget to make the boolean `false` when the `alertController` is dismissed.

Comment: The controller is system driven. iOS handles the alertController. I don't get any reference to the controller.